# Keep getting 'unexpected response, code=404' exception in watir-webdriver

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium, watir, watir-webdriver

I have a test that simply clicks on search button and types username.
in 45% cases I get error `'unexpected response, code=404'` I have no idea why?
I am running test in IE browser, using latest version of watir-webdriver.
Has anybody faced this kind of issues? is there any way around this?

Comment: 404 means that the requested resource doesn't exist - seems to be a problem with the tested application. This is just a blank shot: is it an app deployed on multiple nodes?

Comment: can you include the code for the area where the failure is happening, and the actual error code.  Also what do you see happen in the browser when this error occurs?

Comment: @ChuckvanderLinden unfortunately I can't upload code, corporate rules, but what my code does is simply clicks on a Search button, then when an input field shows up, it waits until input field shows up and enters username. I see no issues with browser, and an application works as it should. But that issue appears randomly, making automation scripts unreliable.

Comment: If you can't tell us the code that is trying to execute when you get the error, it's very hard for us to give you much assistance.  Even if you can just say "it's line 8 of my script, which is trying to do xxx"   otherwise we need to be able to read your mind in order to help you, and most of us have not developed that talent.

Comment: @ChuckvanderLinden I know! That was general question, i am asking if anyone had this kind of error and to understand, in what cases usually watir-webdriver throws that error?

Comment: well a 404 is http response for page not found, so typically it results when something causes a new page to try and load (going to a page, clicking a link that loads a new page, submitting a form that loads a new page) and the url for the page does not exist.   if it's a console error in the browser, it might also be from a failing ajax call.   so have we seen 404 errors? uh yeah, all the time, and the causes range from bad url values to offline servers.

Comment: @ChuckvanderLinden thank you, I think I am going to blame application :)

Comment: you've already described what the code is doing at a high level.  which specifically of those things is happening when you see the error?

Comment: Well, that error is thrown in random actions,  I never know in what moment that error is thrown, it is absolutely random, but mostly in clicking on Search button(which loads up input field), navigating to url(browser successfully opens a website), opening a IE 11 (browser opens up successfully, but again exception is thrown and I assume, my global variable is kind_of? FalseClass)